# TypeError: this.route.paramMap.pipe is not a function #49123

Tags: angular, unit-testing, isolation, jasmin

I am using activated route in my code as below,

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
```

while writing isolated test case i am getting below error

```
TypeError: this.route.paramMap.pipe is not a function
```

I am mocking route object as below,

```
const routeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['paramMap']);
```

How can i resolve the above issue?

I am mocking route object as below,

```
const routeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['paramMap']);
```

Comment: this.route.paramMap.pipe() , I am getting error in pipe

Comment: const routeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ActivatedRoute',['paramMap']); -- without TestBed I am creating unit test